# scrolling top navigation bar

Tags: html, css

im trying to create a navigation bar that is sticky when im scrolling down but when i put position:fixed; on the text so they will scroll down too they overlap. i don't want to use jquery because my prof. says so.

```
   <html>
    <head> <title> My Portfolio </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css"
    href="stylesheet.css"> </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <a href="Index.html"> Home </a>
    <a href="About.html" > ABOUT </a >
    <a href="Projects.html"  >PROJECTS </a >
    <a href="Resume.html" >RESUME </a >
    <a href="Gallery.html" > GALLERY </a >
    <b> </b>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
body{
background-position:fixed;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color:white;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:20px;
}

a{
color:#1b1b1b;
TEXT-DECORATION: NONE;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;



}
b{
top:0;
height:30px;
width: 100%;
background:white;
text-align:left;
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this kind of you are looking for?

check the Demo.
http://jsbin.com/tafofesi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few issues with your code. For one thing, there is no closing tag on your `<ul>`. Some browsers will add these for you, but you shouldn't count on it. Secondly, `<ul></ul>` is an unordered list, which means it needs to have list items (`<li></li>`).

Another thing is that you're treating the `<b>` tag as an element. By default, `<b></b>` is meant to apply a **bold** state to text.

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><b><a href="#">BOLD LINK</a></b></li>
</ul>
```

Your main problem is that you've applied the `position: fixed;` to your links, and not to their container. What you want is for each link to be positioned relative to the other (`position: relative;`). Add a container to your menu (`<ul>`), and make its position fixed. All elements within that container should be positioned relatively or static.

See this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7LTqQ/.